# Lagrange's Algorithm of Reduction

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In the solution described by [Primes of the form $p=X^2+3Y^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985550/primes-of-the-form-p-x23y2)

I haven't learned what is Lagrange's algorithm of reduction. Is this in a standard textbook? I can't seem to find it online. I know Thue's proof may not work for $p=x^2+3y^2$, so Lagrange's algorithm of reduction may be needed to show something about the discriminants. I think the discriminant may need to stay invariant or be scaled by an integer square.

Here, starting from $px^2+bxy+cy^2$, the discriminant is $b^2-4cp$. We want to pick $b^2-4cp=-12$, which is possible. If this is $(mx+ny)^2+3(kx+ly)^2$ and its discriminant is 12, we can show $|ml-kn|=1$.

This reminds me of adjacent fractions in Farey Fractions or discriminant of a matrix. How do I continue?

Comment: "Gauss gave a superior reduction algorithm in Disquisitiones Arithmeticae, which ever since has been the reduction algorithm most commonly given in textbooks."

Answer (score 1):

I usually call it Gauss reduction...  if you have a positive prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3,$  you know that $(-3|p) = 1,$ so that there is a solution $\beta$  such that $$  \beta^2 \equiv -3 \pmod p$$
Next,
$$  (2 \beta)^2 \equiv -12 \pmod {4p}$$
and $ (2 \beta)^2 = -12 + 4pt.$ Note that $t > 0$  since $p \geq 7.$
We arrive at a non-reduced form
$$  \langle p, 2 \beta, t \rangle $$
of discriminant $-12.$

It takes a bit of inequalities to confirm class number one for (positive) primitive forms of that discriminant. Caution, there is imprimitive form $  \langle 2,2,2 \rangle $

So far, we have form $  \langle p, 2 \beta, t \rangle .$   Now, Gauss reduction takes the form to the one reduced class, $  \langle 1,0,3 \rangle $

Half the Hessian of the constructed form is
$$
H=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \beta \\
\beta & t \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Half the Hessian of the reduced form is
$$
G=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In matrices (of the Hessian matrices, or half of each...)  we arrive at an integer matrix $P$ of determinant $1$  such that $P^T H P = G.$  If we then save space by naming $Q = P^{-1}$  we reach
$$ Q^T G Q = H.  $$

Let's give names for the entries of $Q,$  let

Let's give names for the entries of $Q,$  let
$$
Q=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
m & n \\
o & r \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
Q^T=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
m & o \\
n & r \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

finally
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
m & o \\
n & r \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
m & n \\
o & r \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \beta \\
\beta & t \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

So
$$ m^2 + 3 o^2 = p  $$

Comment: So G corresponds to x^2+3y^2 and H corresponds to px^2+beta xy + ty^2 and you take derivatives?

Comment: @KaiWang just the matrix of second partial derivatives. For $ax^2 + bxy + c y^2$ it is $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2a & b \\
b & 2c \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ while if $b$ is even we can take half, matrix  $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b/2 \\
b/2 & c \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Why is the Hessian transformation valid?

Comment: @KaiWang What book might you have available for this? The one I like is Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. Probably easier to find Cox.  Anyway, take the Hessian, on the right put a column vector with entries $x,y$  and on the left the row vector $(x,y)$  Now multiply out, the reult is a one by one matrix, we then forget it was a matrix and just use the nu,mber

Comment: https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/Courses/Chapter4.pdf ?

Comment: I don't have any books so far, I'm trying to explore this part of math